# Using the weekly sales function, find the rate at which weekly sales are changing

Tags: calculus, functions

Using the weekly sales function $s=1980+45x+0.65x^2$ with $x$ representing weekly advertising costs, find the rate at which the weekly sales are changing when the weekly advertising costs are 8400 dollars and these costs are increasing at a rate of 1250 dollars per week

Comment: Honestly, Nothing. I don't even comprehend it. :(

Comment: You know how to do derivatives?

Comment: I only know how to do like very simple derivative functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us define the rate at which weekly sales are changing to be $\frac{dS}{dT}$

Let us define the rate at which weekly advertising costs are changing to be $\frac{dx}{dT}$

Let us define the change in weekly sales with respect to change in advertising costs to be 
$\frac{dS}{dx}$

$S=1980+45x+.65x^2$

$\frac{dS}{dT}$ = $\frac{dS}{dx}$*$\frac{dx}{dT}$

$\frac{dS}{dT}$ = $(45+1.3x)$*$\frac{dx}{dT}$

Now evaluate $\frac{dS}{dT}$

at x = $8400,  $$\frac{dx}{dT}$ = 1250

Comment: 13,706,250? is that right ?

Comment: that is the correct value, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (note I won't give the exact answer as this looks like homework)

Define $n$ as the week number.

Write $x(n)$ which is the weekly advertising cost as a function of which week it is.

Use this to write $s(n)$.

Take the derivative of $s(n)$ as a function of $n$.

A better way is to take the derivative of the original function with respect to $n$. For this, you have to remember "derivative of the inside times the derivative of the outside".  AKA, if $f(x)=Ax^b$ then $\frac {df} {dn} = \frac {df} {dx}\frac {dx} {dn} = Abx^{b-1}\frac {dx} {dn}$. You know that at the time that matters, $\frac {dx}{dn} = 1250$